# Will 2*2GB and 2*4GB sets of dual channel RAMS work?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

I intend the following setup :

- Slot 1 (Black ): **UDIMM** 2GB ADATA DDR3-1333 1.5V 9CAS   AD3U1333C2G9-R
- Slot 2 (Yellow): **DIMM**  4GB ADATA DDR3-1333 1.5V 9-9-9  AD3U1600W4G11
- Slot 3 (Black ): **UDIMM** 2GB ADATA DDR3-1333 1.5V 9CAS   AD3U1333C2G9-R
- Slot 4 (Yellow): **DIMM**  4GB ADATA DDR3-1333 1.5V 9-9-9  AD3U1600W4G11

Motherboard : Asus B85M-G

Reason for such a setup:
I have one 2GB Ram and wish to upgrade.  2*4GB has maximum Value for money.  So plan to purchase that.  I wish to use existing 2GB, so plan to purchase another 2GB.

Doubt :

- Will there be any issues?
- If not, will I get the the result of two dual channel setups? (One 2GB dual channel and one 4GB dual channel)
- If I have only 3 RAMS (Two 4GB and One 2GB), will I get better overall performance if i avoid the 2GB RAM?

Comment: In your post both regular "DIMMs" and and unbuffered DIMMs ("UDIMM") are the same. Not sure why you make to distinction in your post.

Comment: :-)  Reason being I was not aware.  So I decided to provide that additional detail assuming it might make a difference.

Comment: Most regular DIMMs are unbuffered DIMMs. So uDIMM, UDIMM and DIMM are the same.
Exception: When talking about server hardware where registered/buffered or FBDIMMs may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will there be any issues?

Probably not.

There are no generic reason why it should not work, though some motherboards have had weird issues. In general try if you have a no name motherboard then everything will work. If you have a brand motherboard (like Compaq, Dell or HP) then those tend to be incompatible with the generally accepted standards.

> If not, will I get the the result of two dual channel setups? (One 2GB dual channel and one 4GB dual channel)

Yes. 2x2GB and 2x4GB should allow dual channel access to both sets of DIMMs.

> If I have only 3 RAMS (Two 4GB and One 2GB), will I get better overall performance if i avoid the 2GB RAM?

It depends.

If you have a single program using a limited a amount of memory then 2x4GB in dual channel mode is often 1% to 10% faster. If you have programs (and OS dis buffers) using more then 4GB then 6GB will be faster.

See also:

- [Is it better to have 4GB RAM in dual channel or 6GB as single channel?](https://superuser.com/questions/229908/is-it-better-to-have-4gb-ram-in-dual-channel-or-6gb-as-single-channel?rq=1)
- [Help with RAM speeds? and Is dual Channel worth it?](https://superuser.com/questions/269244/help-with-ram-speeds-and-is-dual-channel-worth-it)
- [One 8 GB DIMM vs two 4 GB DIMMs in dual channel mode](https://superuser.com/questions/558520/one-8-gb-dimm-vs-two-4-gb-dimms-in-dual-channel-mode)

And a few others. Temped to flag it as duplicate off one of these.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me a lot.  I did go through some of the possible duplicates before posting this question.  I felt the need to as because no other question seemed to cover all the objectives and constraints with reference to my situation.

Comment: If there is no single good answer (even after thorough searching) then new canonical post might be needed.